# How to make the callback function run after the button is created and clicked?

Tags: plotly-dash

I'm very new to Dash and I'm trying to create a map with clickable dots on it, dots are the positions of places. A User can add the clicked position to his/her saved places by click the dot and click a button created by clicking it in a Div next to the map. **My problme is that after the button is created(User clicked the dot), the callback function for button will run automatically(print the coordinate), but what I need is running the function(print the coordinate) when user clicks the button.**

Here is the code:

```
@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('button_list', 'children'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('map', 'clickData')])
def display_click_data(clickData):
    if clickData is None:
        return 'Click on any points to see more info'
    else:
        coordinate_lon = clickData['points'][0]['lon']
        coordinate_lat = clickData['points'][0]['lat']
        coor = str(coordinate_lon)+","+str(coordinate_lat)
        return html.Button('add to saved locations', id='add_to_saved', value=coor),\
               html.Div(id='button_return', children=[])
```

As you can see, the function will return a button in the id='button_list' part, and a coordinate saved in the value of the Button named 'add to saved locations'. And I created a callback function for the button:

```
@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('button_return', 'children'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('add_to_saved','value')],
)
def add_to_saved(value):
    print(value)
    return
```

**I want to print the value(the coordinates) when the button is clicked, but right now this function will automatically run after the button created(user click the dot)** Please help! Thank you for the help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add a component to the layout in this way, the related callback will run. However, the button should have `n_clicks=0` at the time, so  you can use that to your advantage. Try this callback:

```py
@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('button_return', 'children'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('add_to_saved','n_clicks')],
)
def add_to_saved(value):
    if value:
        print(value)
        return value
    return ''
```

Edit: changed `Input` prop to `n_clicks`

Comment: thank you for the reply, after I add the n_click=0 to the button and change the callback function to your answer, the problem is still the same. Did I misunderstand something?

Comment: I made a mistake in the callback I used. My edit contains the fix. It should only work when the button has been clicked. However, you may need to add a `State` for some other component to get the data you're looking to add to the `children` of the output component.